# How do I use the CSS box-model to make sure my body is spaced from the edge of the window despite being 100% high?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres

I am trying to complete one of the last steps in this tutorial that I linked above and I can't seem to get my box to adjust to the edged of the screen when I zoom. Instead the text only zooms in and out. I feel like I have a decent understanding of the box model but I just can't get the code just right. If someone would give me a hand that would be great. Here is a link to an example page that adjusts the way I would like it to when I zoom.

http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres/test.html

This is what I have so far...

```
html {
    height:100%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #c72;
}

body {
    width:68%;
    height:100%;
    margin:1.5% auto;
    padding:1.7%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding to html

```
html {
   height: 100%;
   padding: 40px 0 100px 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background: #c72;
}
```

Then you can remove the top/bottom margin on body

```
body {
   ...
   margin: 0 auto;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I got the issue resolved and I have a much better understanding of this concept now.

Answer (score 0):

You've got `height:100%;` applied to the `body` tag, then applied further margins. This results in a height greater than 100%, hence the spillover.

All you need is to have a total of height, padding and margins no greater than 100% and the problem goes away:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #c72;
}

body {
    width:68%;
    height:90%;
    margin:5% auto;
    padding:1.7%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
```

With this setup, your `body` now has a *combined* height of 100%, made up of 90% height, then 2x5% top and bottom margins.

This is how the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) works, padding and margins are calculated *after* the width/height is specified. [Here's a little history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug#Background) if you're keen to know why.

This is very handy to know if you get into [responsive web design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/), as using percentages to calculate widths, margins and padding is very handy indeed.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I got the issue resolved and I have a much better understanding of this concept now.